# Notification of new replies and contacting users via mail

Tags: feature-request

When I reply to someone on here and he is not immediately watching the page, I don't get an reply at all.

Even though I put my email in here I don't get any notifications about replies and so don't other members.

Also I cannot contact other members there's no "contact me" link.

So I want

1. Notification via email as a standard if a comment or reply was made
2. A contact-me link on every user's page to contact him via mail or private message.

Comment: I am downvoting for point two and I like how they have done point 1 and it is already being done. You cant imaging how many emails top users would get from people wanting them to "FIX MAY COEDS"

Answer (score 4):

By default, the StackExchange sends users very little email. You can change the settings by clicking on the StackExchange menu on the top left of the screen, and selecting "email settings" at the bottom of the box that pops up. This should email you any time something pops up in your StackExchange inbox. By default, if something is in your inbox, a red dot appears over the StackExchange logo on the top left.

Here are a few ways that something can end up in your inbox:

- Someone posts an answer to your question
- Someone posts a comment on a question or answer you own
- Someone mentions you using the @user tag in a comment thread where you posted a comment
- Someone mentions you using the @user tag in chat

One of the reasons StackExchange does not promote private communication is that it potentially hides information needed to solve questions (or prevents answers from being written). Another major reason is that it turns SPAM into a public problem that the community can monitor and address.

Answer (score 4):

I really wouldn't want to give other users the ability to send me email without my consent.  When you answer a bunch of questions on a email list, forum, or here, too many people think they have the right to use you as their private unpaid consultant.  I get enough emails as it is where people have dug out my address.  I don't want it to be even easier.

There is no reason these messages need to be private.  I just delete them without reply because I don't want to engage in a private dialog.  Too many people can't seem to understand that there is absolutely no upside for people to *privately* help someone without getting paid.

In case you think I'm just making this up, here is a recent typical such message:

```
Dear Olin,

I saw that you have programmed bootloaders that can be upgraded
remotely via internet.

I am currently using Microchip's USB HID bootloader for PIC32MX
series of microcontrollers.

The bootloader works okay with the PIC32UBL.exe program provided, but
I would like to do away with the user having to install a program,
and simply have the device update via a web page using javascript or
some widely browser supported language. This would be for code
updates and also for programming user changeable parameters. I would
guess someone has done something like this.

A few questions:
1) Is this possible?
2) What would you suggest as the simplest method?
3) Can this be done without implementing a TCPIP stack (i.e. via a
browser rather than through a dedicated IP address)?
4) If this is possible, and you have done it or parts of it, do you
have any code that you would be willing to share, or can you at least
point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
TC
```

This came from "selfknows@gmail.com".  Note the complete lack of any reason this shouldn't have been posted to the appropriate forum or whatever.  This guy doesn't even identify himself, and seems to want free help, but for me to do it privately just for him.

The above is quite typical, and probably happens a couple of times a month now.  If you let the unwashed masses send private messages to any other user, it would happen much more often and get really annoying.

Comment: And if you wanted anyone to be able to contact you then you could opt-in by putting your email in the public part of your profile.